# Post Response as a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have a method "create" inside my controller, but once I create my model, instead of showing the model itself, I want my view to show just the URL of that model, eg: "http://www.myapp.com/model/1".

I defined another action inside my controller, which is called "url", and once the model is saved (inside create method), I am doing like this:

```
format.html { render :action => "url" }
```

So in this url view I want to show the full url of my model.

How can I get the model url to place there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `url_for` method that is available in every controller.

```
url_for(:action => 'login', :controller => 'members', 
        :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
```

would result in (example):

```
http://www.example.com/members/login/
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for

---

And as answered before me (apparently the answer was deleted), you can call `url_for` by giving it an object as well (such as a newly created model instance):

```
# Create a new instance of a model:
@new_order = Order.new(...)
# And then get the url for that specific instance's location:
url_for(@new_order)
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: url_for! that's what I was looking for, tnx a lot man!! Let me just ask you something else. This external app made this POST on my app (received on my create action), and I should not return an HTML but just a string with this url, how should I handle this response??

Comment: No problem :) You can do this by calling `render text: url_for(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the action to your config/routes.rb

```
get "model", :to => "model#url"
```

Or for a member action

```
get "model", :to => "model#url", :on => :member
```

Comment: I don't know if I or you misunderstood. The thing is, I don't want to override my show action, ex: if I have a GET at myapp/model/1, I want to see my model as I defined in show.html.erb. What I want is, when a user create a model, not be redirected to that show action, but to this url action, where it's gonna have just the full URL "http://www.myapp.com/model/1". My question is, how can I have this URL of the model that was just created. Got that? Tnx!

Comment: Oh.  I assumed from your question that you had an action you wanted to render called url, for some reason.  url_for like @Nico Hämäläinen said is what you want.